# How Generics allows strong type checking for Type Casting errors during Compile Time

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have been trying to understand type checking and type casting. I have understood the concept of Type casting for Collections using Generics but where does Generics allows strong type Checking for illegal Type Casting other than Collections. Can someone provide me with an example where there is a type casting error during compile time and Generics handle this effectively.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Take this case, for example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pair<Integer, Integer> p1 = new Pair<Integer, Integer>(3, 5);
        Pair<String, Integer> p2 = (Pair<String, Integer>) p1;

        Pair p = new Pair<Integer, Integer>(3, 5);
        Pair<String, Integer> p3 = (Pair<String, Integer>) p;
    }

    static class Pair<A, B> {
        A first;
        B second;

        public Pair(A a, B b) {
            first = a;
            second = b;
        }
    }
}
```

Because of generics, `Pair<String, Integer> p2 = (Pair<String, Integer>) p1` will raise a compilation error.

But since `p` does not use generics, there is no compile-time error thrown for the `p3 = (Pair<String, Integer>) p` step, which can cause issues later on.

Answer (score 0):

JPA makes use of generics in `TypedQuery`s to ensure that the expected type is returned. If you ask for a `Customer`, the type system knows to treat the results of the query as `Customer` objects and not as a plain `Object` you have to cast yourself, and if you use the Criteria API, it can also verify that your query parameters refer to valid attributes of the `Customer` class.

Answer (score 0):

One of the examples outside of Collections would be when classes implement a `generic` Interface. For example, `Comparable<T>` is implemented by `Integer` as

```
Integer implements Comparable<Integer>
```

to make sure that only `Integer` instances can be compared with an `Integer`.

The *generic* `compareTo()` method is defined in the interface as

```
public interface Comparable<T> {    
    public int compareTo(T o);
}
```

The `Integer` class implements it as

```
public class Integer implements Comparable<Integer> {
    // ...
    public int compareTo(Integer anotherInteger) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very basic example would be an abstract class for building objects:

```
public abstract class BuilderBase<T, P> {
    public T build(P parameter);
}
```

An implementation could be something like something like

```
public class IntBuilder extends BuilderBase<Integer, String> {
    public Integer build(String parameter) {
        return Integer.parse(parameter);
    }
}
```

Without generics, the `build` signature would have to be

```
public Object build(Object parameter)
```

As such, the compiler would provide little to no help in checking that the input and output is of the right type, forcing one to do potentially unsafe typecasts during runtime.

(Disclaimer: This is a bit of an oversimplification due to covariance and stuff.)

Comment: Thanks for all the examples but these involves directly generics. Can anyone give me a non-generic example which throws type cast errors other than casting with Class Names and show me how to how to handle it using generics